# Dynamically add check box and records from database in javaFX 2.2 Table View

Tags: checkbox, tableview, javafx-2

I am writing a client-server java FX application with a table View. I have a database in the server side and I want from the Client to load the table Columns and table Records from the db to a table View dynamically. So far I have found many hints, on how to do this successfully. The thing is that I want to add to the table a column 'select' which is a check box. Below is my code.

```
private void AddToTableRecordsFromDB(TabPane tp){
    tableview = (TableView) tp.lookup("#table");
    ObservableList<Object> data = null;
    try {
        String[] columnNames = (String[]) Login.Login.in.readObject();
        ArrayList<ArrayList> al = (ArrayList<ArrayList>) Login.Login.in.readObject();
        /**********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         **********************************/
                TableColumn select = new TableColumn("Select");
                select.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("invited"));
                select.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ObservableValue, Boolean>, TableCell<ObservableValue, Boolean>>() {

                    public TableCell<ObservableValue, Boolean> call(TableColumn<ObservableValue, Boolean> p) {
                        return new CheckBoxTableCell<ObservableValue, Boolean>();
                    }
                });
                tableview.getColumns().add(select);

        for(int i=0 ; i<columnNames.length; i++){
            //use non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;  
            TableColumn col;
                col = new TableColumn(columnNames[i]);
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                   
                    @Override
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                             
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                     
                    }                   
                });                  

            tableview.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        /********************************
         * Data added to ObservableList *
         ********************************/
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for(int i=0 ; i<al.size(); i++){
            ObservableList<ArrayList> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList(al.get(i));
            data.add(row);
        }
        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        tableview.setItems(data);

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Developer_Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

}
```

I took the CheckBoxTableCell class from the JavaFX2.0 Ensemble.
The database loads successfully in to the table view and also my 'select' column is created, but I can not see any check boxes in the rows.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using "non property style" to add columns dynamically, and your table view made of list of list items. I guess there is no `getInvited()` method in those data structure model. However by setting `select.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("invited"));` the table column will look for that method. Set cell value factory with valid value.

**EDIT**: I didn't test but can you try the code below.

```
select.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> p) {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().get(0).toString());
    }
});
```

Note the `get(0)`. Namely it would be better if `readObject()` returns at least 1 item. Another note is `CheckBoxTableCell` needs a Callback which returns `ObservableProperty<Boolean>` and binds bidirectionally so I think it is better to implement your own cell factory containing checkbox, regarding to your data model.

Comment: Yes I can understand that is no use to have this select.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("invited"));  in my code. To be more specific, I want the list records I retrieve from the database to have StringProperty and just be able to show them in the TableView. I can achieve that from the code above. The problem is that I want to add one more column to the table with check boxes. I do not know how to manage the list I retrieve and the select column. Probably the example from javaFX ensemble is not what i am looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have already tested this and as a result, my 'select' column is filled with string values, which are the same with the first column values returned from the query. This code creates a StringProperty value for the TableCell of the specified column. I must find a way to create a BooleanProperty to display a checkbox.

Comment: @GeorgePap. Just a hint. Extend the list and add a BooleanProperty field with getter getSelected() for example. Then init the list of booleanProplist. Finally set select.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("selected"));. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried many things, including the suggestion of Uluk Biy but I have not resolve my problem yet. I Have a List of Objects returned by the sql query. A Boolean type, of which I want to create the table column containing the check Boxes and String objects, of which I want to display simple strings.